# Quais os usos mais comuns de "barriga", "pança", "papo", "abdômen" e "ventre" em uma frase?

Tags: uso-de-palavras

De um modo geral, essas palavras referem-se àquela parte do corpo humano que fica abaixo do tórax e acima dos membros inferiores.

Por exemplo, a expressão "de papo pro ar" significa "estar descansando" e às vezes, literalmente "de barriga pra cima".  Embora, ***nesse sentido***, "papo signifique "abdômen", "de papo pro ar" é uma frase feita e ninguém diria "Tá de abdomen pro ar, hein malandro?"

Pergunto então, quais os usos mais comuns para cada uma dessas palavras?

A minha pergunta tem como objetivo facilitar o entendimento para aqueles que estudam o Português como segunda língua.

Comment: Para mim, "papo" normalmente tem dois sentidos: (1) conversa (que é o mais frequente no português coloquial), e (2) a parte da garganta imediatamente anterior ao queixo. O Wikicioário diz que "papo" é uma parte do corpo das aves, onde algumas guardam alimentos para seus filhotes. De qualquer maneira, eu nunca ouvi "papo" sendo usado como sinônimo de barriga.

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim É usado na expressão "de papo pro ar", comum no Brasil, com o sentido de "barriga".  As outras expressões (bater um papo, papo-furado, etc), não se referem ao abdômen.  Isoladamente é aquilo que você citou. O pelicano o tem bem desenvolvido e as pessoas obesas também o desenvolvem.

Comment: Para mim, "de papo pro ar" não quer dizer que a barriga está para o ar, mas sim que a cabeça está reclinada para trás, deixando... o papo para o ar!

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim O Aurélio, segunda edição, definição nº 4 diz: (pop) barriga, estômago, fole, além da definição que você conhece. E, "de papo pro ar", sem fazer nada, desocupado, ocioso.

Comment: Interessante; infelizmente, eu não consigo pensar em nenhum uso da palavra "papo" como sinônimo de "barriga".

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim   O único que eu conheço é "de papo pro ar" e nesse caso realmente significa barriga, pelo menos no ptBR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27448/discussion-between-arthur-azevedo-de-amorim-and-centaurus).

Comment: O papo é uma espécie de "estômago" das aves, portanto, "de papo para o ar" é o papo da ave para o ar, o pescoço.

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim - *De papo cheio* = De barriga cheia. *Está no hora de encher o papo* = Está na hora de comer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Barriga

Em geral é o termo mais usado, sobretudo em um contexto coloquial, embora não seja necessariamente informal. Aparece em expressões como "de barriga cheia", "de barriga para baixo", etc. Acho que é seguro dizer que, quando em dúvida sobre qual usar, "barriga" é uma boa opção.

## Pança

Segundo o [Wikicionário](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/pan%C3%A7a), "pança" em primeiro lugar se refere a um dos estômagos de ruminantes como o boi. Por extensão, é uma palavra para se referir a uma barriga grande, e em geral possui conotação jocosa ou pejorativa. Não se usa "pança" para se referir a barrigas normais em geral; pode-se encontrá-la ocasionalmente em expressões como "de pança cheia".

## Abdômen

É um termo em geral mais técnico, usado por médicos ou para se referir aos músculos da barriga, por exemplo para falar de exercícios ("vou fazer abdominais", "os músculos da região abdominal", etc.). Não é comum encontrá-la em contextos como "estou de abdômen cheio" (para dizer que se comeu demais), por exemplo. Também é usado em [contextos biológicos](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/abdome.html), significando "parte posterior dos insetos e de outros articulados".

## Ventre

É provavelmente a mais raramente usada das quatro. Em geral, usa-se para falar:

1. da [dança do ventre](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan%C3%A7a_do_ventre);
2. da [prisão de ventre](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pris%C3%A3o_de_ventre);
3. para se referir à gravidez ("no ventre da mãe");
4. e em literaturas antigas, como textos bíblicos (com exceção das traduções mais modernas), como em "*Eis que (...) seu poder está nos músculos de seu ventre*" ou "... *sobre o teu ventre rastejarás* ...").

Mas em si, ventre significa ["barriga"](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/ventre.html). 　E também ["útero"](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/ventre.html), no caso do sentido maternal.

Comment: No caso de ventre, também é usado em "prisão de ventre", e em textos bíblicos (ex.: "Quando comer, em sua boca será doce, mas em seu ventre se tornará amargo.").  E abdômen também é bastante comum em contextos biológicos quando se referindo a pequenos animais e insetos.

Comment: Bem lembrado, Bruno. Se quiser, pode completar minha resposta diretamente.

Comment: "Baixo-ventre" també,m é uma expressão usada e reconhecida, se bem que não muito comum.

Comment: @ANeves  "baixo-ventre" é utilizado frequentemente por médicos quando a paciente é uma mulher nos últimos meses de gestação.  Nesses casos é mais comum relatar "a paciente apresenta dor no baixo ventre"  do que "apresenta dor no andar inferior do abdomen".

Comment: "Região ventral" pode ser usado para descrever o espaço ocupado pela barriga e pela virilha. Eu acho que "ventre" é mais abrangente que os demais termos.